# Use Bicep for Docker related things (build, push, pull, delete old versions, execute npm commands etc)

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-bicep

I've started to look at Bicep to build Azure pipelines, hoping to keep down complexity. The concept of small, separated, reusable Bicep Resources that you can pass parameters to is really nice.

It would be nice to avoid one big, complex `azure-pipelines.yml` file with all details in it.

I'm now trying to build and push a Docker image to a Azure Container registry. Having Googled and tried different approaches this is the most simple way of doing this that I've found:

```yaml
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build Docker image and push it to ContainerRegistry'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(azureServiceConnection)
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      az acr build -f $(sourceCodePath)/Dockerfile -t $(dockerImageName):{{.Run.ID}} -r $(containerRegistryName) .
```

My problem with this is that the code needs to be in the `azure-pipelines.yml` file.
I'd like this functionality in a `.bicep` file instead.

Reading on the subject has pointed me to creating this kind of Bicep resource:

```
resource dockerBuildAndPush 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = { 
...
properties: {
  azCliVersion: '2.9.1'
  scriptContent: 'az acr build -f /xxx/Dockerfile -t dockerimagename:tag -r containerregistryname .'
  }
}
```

But running that code does not work. It seems some kind of user with certain access rights etc is needed. My feeling is that things are getting complex.

Is there a simple way of doing what I want to do using Bicep?

Comment: Bicep is used to deploy/maintain azure infrastructure. Not really suitable for code deployment. As you said you can run deploymentScripts. Another approach is to use ACR Tasks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-tasks-overview